# Linking datagridview to MS Access table with OleDB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, oledb

I want to link datagridview to my existing MS Access table through OleDB.

I have multiple tables named "Groups","Groups2", "Groups3" etc.

By clicking respective button on form (https://i.stack.imgur.com/taQ9m.png) I'm loading one table to datagridview.

I need to link datagridview to Access so I can save any edits I made in datagrid.

I tried this code:
http://codepad.org/5PSz4LsB

I'm experimenting with functions  `Monday_Click`  and `Save_Click`

> Exception thrown: system.data.oledb.oledbexception Syntax Error in
>   UPDATE Statement in da.Update(timetable) command.

That's really strange, because OleDbCommandBuilder is supposed to create insert\delete\update queries.

I've tried different solutions from Stackoverflow and other sources, but it didn't work.

Update: Apparently OleDBCommandBuilder doesn't work with '-' in columns names, so I removed this sign from names and it worked just fine.

Comment: your Monday_Click button is working ? I mean are you able to fetch records of monday ?

Comment: Yes, retrieving of records was working just fine and i actually found the problem - it was in column name of my table. They had '-' sign in them and it apparently doesn't work.